# Html video attachment

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble attaching a video in my html file. I used a youtube video for this one but whenever I open it on my browser it says the video is unavailable because youtube refused to connect. I also tried attaching a video from my computer that ended with .mov and that didnt work either. here is what i wrote in html for the youtube one.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/u9fftcQGSa0"
  frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; 
  gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: yes, tell us What you wrote in the html?

Comment: Yes complete the question. paste your html to be more specific about problem.

Answer (score 0):

For using YouTube videos in your website, go to the video > Share > embed. Take the HTML code snippet and paste it in your desired place.

Answer (score 0):

**For local server video attachment in your website:**

```
<video width="1080px" height="720px" controls="controls"/>
    <source src="write your video location/link here with extension" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Example:

```
<video width="1080px" height="720px" controls="controls"/>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**For YouTube video attachment in your website:**

Step 1:

- Go to YouTube and select/open your video,
- Go to share option,
- Click Embed,
- Copy Embed link

Step 2: Go to your html code and paste your YouTube embed code

Example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uzumIYBSaWY" 
    title="YouTube video player" 
    frameborder="0" 
    allow="accelerometer; 
    autoplay; 
    clipboard-write; 
    encrypted-media; 
    gyroscope; 
    picture-in-picture" 
    allowfullscreen
>
</iframe>
```